# WSO2 Single Sign-Out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wso2, wso2-identity-server

we have tow applications with a different domain (app.auth & app.openId), we applied SSO on them using wso2 OpenID Connect and was successful, after that we tried to apply single sign-out from all applications as mention in this link

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+OpenID+Connect+Single+Logout

when I click Logoff from one application it redirects me to OpenID CONNECT LOGOUT

https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/oauth2_logout_consent.do

after we press yes to logout ,Wso2 redirect me to the client application 
but we found that the tow applications still logged in

this is my code for log out

```
    public void LogOff()
    {
        string idtalken = Session["id_token"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("https://localhost:9443/oidc/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri="+ UrlHelper + "/&id_token_hint=" + idtalken);
    }
```

after we tried to delete cookies before redirect to WSO2 server, but we found the only logout from the current application because we delete the cookies that related to its domain only, this is the code :

```
  public void LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        string idtalken = Session["id_token"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("https://localhost:9443/oidc/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri="+ UrlHelper + "/&id_token_hint=" + idtalken);
    }
```

Please any help for single logout from all application

Comment: have you analyzed the http traffic? does the session state change on application side?

Comment: WSO2 Identity Server 5.2.0 only support OIDC Session Management[1] protocol. Have you implemented the required iframes for the protocol work?
[1]: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html